# Do these one parameter subgroups generate the Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of dimension $d$. Choose a basis $B$ for $\mathfrak{g}$. From the $d$ elements of $B$, we obtain $d$ one-parameter subgroups of $G$. Let $H$ be the smallest subgroup of $G$ that contains all of these $d$ one-parameter subgroup.

> Is the closure of $H$ equal to $G$ necessarily? Is it true under some conditions such as "$G$ is compact/semisimple"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\overline H=G$. That is so because, by Cartan's theorem, $\overline H$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$ and, by your assumptions, if $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak h$ are the Lie algebras of $G$ and $H$ respectively, then $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak h$. So, the connected component of $e$ in $G$ is $H$. But, since we are assuming that $G$ is connected, what this means is that $G$ is $H$.

Comment: Thank you! Is it really possible for $H$ not to be closed? I was not sure.

Comment: I think you mean that $\bar{H}$ is a Lie subgroup.

Comment: I think so, but right now I am unable to provide an example.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sure! I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @AmericanIgor This should be a separate question.